# How to set up port forward to SSL site hosted in Virtual Box VM

Tags: ssl, iis, virtual-machine, virtualbox, portforwarding

I want to setup port forwarding for ssl and non-ssl sites. I tried to test this set up using virtual box like below

**Non-ssl sites**

1. I configured to run win 2012 server in virtual box on my Windows 10 Machine
2. I hosted site in windows 2012 server with port of 5001
3. In Network setting of the virtual box, I set it up like to forward request coming to 5002 to 5001 VM hosted site (refer image below). It is working fine
   [image]

**SSL Sites**

1. Create self-signed certificate in IIS
2. Added https binding using self-signed certificated create above, it works ok with VM
3. Add port forwarding Host port as 443 and Guest port as 443 but it is not working when access from external machine

I am not sure what mistake am doing, Any help will be appreciated

Thanks.